# To not pass an argument due to a condition

Tags: c++, c++11, ternary-operator, default-arguments

I have this function declaration:

```
void do_somthing(int a,int b,foo bar = foo());
```

I want to call it for some arguments as follow:

```
foo bar = get_bar_by_some_algorithm();
int a = 5,b = 6;
if(bar.empty()){
    do_somthing(a,b);
}
else{
    do_somthing(a,b,bar);
}
```

I want to get rid of the `if` statement. So, I did it like this:

```
foo bar = get_bar_by_some_algorithm();
int a = 5,b = 6;
do_somthing(a,b,bar.empty()?foo():bar);
```

However, my approach is acceptable (is it good even?) if `do_somthing` is stable from default argument point of view but if it changed to something like this:

```
void do_somthing(int a,int b,foo bar = get_special_foo());
```

My code will be outdated because `foo()` is not equal too `get_special_foo()`.

The question is How can I use `?` operator or any short equivalent to pass an argument in case of non-empty and **NOT Passing** anything in case of empty?

Example for clarification (Imaginary syntax):

```
do_somthing(a,b,bar.empty()? the_default_argument : bar);
```

Comment: Both ternary operator and `if` would do a branch, BTW.

Comment: You can just pass in `bar` and do the `if(bar.empty())` check in `do_somthing`.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with the ternary operator was okay, but seemed unnecessary.  It's not normal to slap in new default values for functions at a later date without considering the consequences.  If your default value is not meaningful, then something is wrong with your design in the first place.

But just to entertain you, here's a branchless version.  I *might* consider something like this if my main concern was a measured bottleneck due to branch misprediction.  I would not normally do this, because it's less clear than a simple *if-statement*:

```
static auto do_something[2] = {
    +[]( int a, int b, foo bar ) { do_something( a, b, bar ); },
    +[]( int a, int b, foo bar ) { do_something( a, b ); }
};
do_something[bar.empty()]( a, b, bar );
```

Comment: You trade branch prediction to jump prediction.

Comment: No, because the compiler should elide the lambda to a pure function call, which was going to happen anyway.  In any case, it was merely an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't use `?:` for this.

The specification of `?:` ternary operator requires all three operands to be valid expressions.  A valid expression (over-simplistically) is a construct that evaluates one or more values, (optionally) acts on the values using operators, and produces a result.

An expression with nothing in it is a contradiction:  it doesn't evaluate anything, so cannot be an operand of the `?:` operator.

Note:  it is possible to have an empty statement (e.g. by having an isolated `;`).    But an empty statement is not an expression.

The obvious solution to hide the `if()` away would be to do the test inside your function, as mentioned in comments by CompuChip.   Or write a wrapper function that does the test for you (and ensure that your `do_somthing()` is not declared in any other compilation unit, to avoid temptation of calling it directly rather than the wrapper).